# No me aplica CSS en móvil

Tags: css, web

Estoy haciendo una web sencilla, con html y CSS. Nunca había adaptado una para dispositivos móviles, y me está dando verdaderos quebraderos de cabeza.

Para empezar la web se me adapta mejor cuando la veo en el móvil sin distinciones (los textos se me ajustan a la perfección, el único problema son las imágenes, excepto en una de las páginas, donde reduce el tamaño del texto, sin aparentemente tener nada diferente).
Pero bueno esto ya lo resolveré por mi cuenta, espero.

El problema viene creando la distinción en css con @media screen... tras volverme loco, he descubierto que no me aplica las propiedades que añado aquí si ya hay otras que se aplican al CSS original.

Por ejemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    body{
        background-color: red;
    }
    #header{
         background-color:black;
    }
}
```

Bien, pues solo se aplica si en el body y #header 'originales' elimino la propiedad background-color, sino me mantiene la orginal.

Estoy seguro que es una chorrada, pero me estoy volviendo loco con el tema y no encuentro una solución.

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: No te vuelvas loco. Revisa si estás cacheando tu sitio y borra los cachés. Con las reglas CSS suele pasar eso, que a veces se quedan en caché y no ves los cambios por un tiempo (horas, a veces días, dependiendo de cómo esté configurado el cacheo). A veces, aunque no hayas configurado tú el caché, puede que el hosting lo haya hecho, o por ejemplo puede que el sitio esté bajo Cloudfare o algo parecido. En mi sitio estuve un tiempo bajo Cloudfare y probar cambios de este tipo era un verdadero fastidio.

Comment: Tengo la web montada en mi pc con xampp y con un dyndns para acceder en el móvil. He borrado cache y reiniciado el servidor y nada. En principio los cambios se aplican al momento. Pero he detectado otra cosa: sobre el ejemplo que he puesto, en el body no tenia la propiedad: la he añadido y en este caso si me respeta el CSS: en el PC se ve de una manera y en el móvil de otra, sin embargo la del #header me sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Comment: @Carmen en CSS el símbolo `#` es el selector para los `id`, así como el punto es para las clases. Albert, ten en cuenta que CSS se carga en cascada, por tanto tienes que verificar que las reglas no sean sobre-escritas por otras. Ten en cuenta también que si usas `!important` sobre algunos elementos, esto se va a establecer prioritariamente sobre los elementos. Te sugiero que pruebes por partes, y que vayas añadiendo el CSS por bloques, para ir analizando la lógica del mismo. Si no es un problema de caché significa que hay reglas que prevalecen sobre otras por la forma en que tienes organizado.

Comment: Correcto, el # es porque uso el selector ID para identificar el header. El !important no lo uso, pero he probado poniéndolo en la propiedad para móvil y así sí que me lo coge (mientras que en el PC se sigue viendo bien). No creo que sea la mejor solución, pero con esto puedo avanzar mientras lo encuentro. Gracias!

Comment: No se recomienda usar `!important`, más bien hay que evitarlo. Es mejor que analices la lógica, casi seguro que hay algo que se está sobre-escribiendo en alguna parte.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya he encontrado la solución. En el fichero CSS había añadido el código para el `@media` al principio de todo, por lo que entiendo que en primera instancia lo cargaba bien, pero seguía leyendo el .CSS hasta encontrar la parte que lo machacaba. 
Copiando el código del `@media` al final del fichero me funciona perfectamente sin necesidad del !important.
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Es lo que te decía sobre la *cascada*  en uno de los comentarios. Generalmente los media query se ponen al final, no al principio.